# Installing ubuntu on Mac book pro without internal HDD

Tags: mac, external-hdd

I have a macbook Pro (bought in 2013) and I have accidentally fried the internal SSD. Now I don't want to buy new SSD as it is very expensive. I want to install ubuntu on external HDD and want to use as my permanent disk. I have already made the ubuntu bootable USB and I can now run the Linux without installing it. The problem is that I could not install it on the same USB because it doesn't show in the disk list.

Also, how can I make sure that every time I turn on the laptop, it starts automatically with ubuntu when HDD is connected.

Kindly answer me as I am very new to ubuntu.

Comment: For the first question, you'll have have another drive to install Ubuntu to.  You can't install to the drive you're running liveCD from.  As to how to automatically start Ubuntu, look up your BIOS settings.

Comment: @anonymous2 Except for the fact that Macs don't *have* BIOS settings..

Comment: @AndroidDev, good point, they're EFI, aren't they.

Comment: @anonymous2 Well it's worse than that, because you literally can't alter the boot order unless you are inside OSX.

Comment: @AndroidDev in any case I don't expect that to be a problem since the OP is evidently able to boot to the USB, though perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: @anonymous2 thank you very much for the answer. I can start the EFI boot and if I connect external HDD. I am sure I can install the ubuntu on this hdd. but i want to make the changes in boot order that it boots from HDD everytime it is connected . just like we can do with windows. Is there any option in MAC to do this when you dont have the OS X ?

Comment: @codetest, that would be a better question for the [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), I'm afraid.  My knowledge of Mac is very limited.

Comment: @AndroidDev Also, can I install OS X using the same method as well. I don't know if I can get the .iso image for OS X or not. is it possible?

Comment: @codetest, you could check out [this article](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-change-boot-order-set-default-boot-os-in-ubuntu-14-10-15-04-linux-mint-or-other-derivatives) on linuxandubuntu.com, but I don't know enough about Mac to guarantee its success.  Sorry... :(

Comment: @codetest Unfortunately, because Apple will be Apple, you can't download the OSX installer if you aren't inside OSX! Now what I'd suggest for the boot order is to physically remove the SSD from the computer, and hopefully it will be smart enough to boot the next available device. But honestly, just go buy a 2.5" hard drive and and stick it in place of the SSD, because it will only run you like $50

Comment: @anonymous2 No worries, Thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: @codetest As per my previous comment, see this link: http://a.co/eHonXiC

Comment: @AndroidDev Actually, I sent my laptop to Apple and they send me the price for repair which is even more than I expect. they said to me that motherboard should be replaced as the pins are damaged where SSD suppose to connect. Also, I could not find it for 50$. I am from Germany and here i could find it from OWC which cost arround 450€ for 500GB

Comment: @codetest What I'm saying is you could replace it yourself, and here's a link to a $50 HDD: http://a.co/eHonXiC **I would open up the laptop and verify that Apple's claim of damaged pins is accurate...**

Comment: @AndroidDev my laptop have something like https://preisvergleich.check24.de/ssd-festplatten/owc-aura-1tb-owcssdab2mb10.html?utm_medium=glp&wpset=google_pla_shopping_01&bc=pt&gclid=Cj0KEQjwioHIBRCes6nP56Ti1IsBEiQAxxb5G8X87vczLlt1k7CaW8m1WKgit0EIjAzsVDfnBgfbQEQaAoMf8P8HAQ Do you think i can also install other type of SSD ?

Comment: @codetest - What *exact* model MBP do you have?

Comment: @AndroidDev the model is A1502 Macbook pro